# struts-jquery div is not redrawn until http response will be fully loaded

Tags: jquery, performance, jsp, struts

I have a struts-jquery tags on the page, in particular this one.

```
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-jquery-tags" prefix="sj"%>
     ...
    <sj:div id="someId" href="%{myUrl}">..</sj:div>
```

myUrl returns a big amount of data. 
The problem is that until all the data (html) will be loaded to browser (which could take 10-20 seconds) the sj:div doesn't show anything, leaves blank, which makes impression for user that page is stucked.

But, if I just use simple  it looks much better for users - although page is still loading, the screen is updated at once, and for users it looks like page loaded pretty quickly.

So. How can I fix that? I would like to use Struts jquery tags, but without this annoying "bug".

Comment: Take a screenshot of the fully loaded page, put it into that div. When the request has completed it will replace the HTML within the div.

Comment: what a strange idea.. the content of this div is pretty frequently changing, so putting static picture is nonsence. Why it just can't update the content of div piece by piece, not all at once

Comment: because loading it piece-meal could have unintended consequences. It's probably best to show a `loading.gif` image or something then.